# 302 response from webhook subscription callback

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0, outlook-restapi

I'm following the [aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample) project to subscribe users to outlook 365 webhooks.

The code is using ASP.NET Core 1.1 and I would like to run it with ASP.NET Core 2.0. I built a new 2.0 application and pulled the relevant code to the new project.

If I run the 1.1 code I get a `202` response from the `/notification/listen` endpoint.

If I run the 2.0 code I get a `302` response from the `/notification/listen endpoint`

It seems the callback never makes it to the `/notification/listen` endpoint so maybe something in the framework preventing it.

I am using ngrok like the GitHub example and getting this error:

> Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter

When making this call in `/subscription/create`:

```
newSubscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(new Subscription
{
    Resource = $"users/{ userId }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = appSettings.NotificationUrl,
    ClientState = clientState,
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0)
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide some requested  to investigate this issue?

Comment: I believe this was caused by ngrok, ssl, and something that had been updated in dotnet core 2.0.  If I remember I worked around the issue by pushing to azure and testing instead of getting this solution running locally.   sorry for the late reply, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.
It seems you're having an issue with the sample itself. The best thing to do in that case is to create an issue on the repository of the sample so it gets addressed and fixed.